# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I used oracle in my application.

I have problem using this code :

```
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
    import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.Query;
    ....
    ....
    .....

     public void insertGR(String id,String num) {


                String query = "execute md_pkg.insert_Gr("+id+"," + num + ")";


                SQLQuery sqlQuery = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(query);
                sqlQuery.executeUpdate();



            }
```

in jboss consol I have this error :

```
SQL Error: 900, SQLState: 42000
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement


org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
    at
```

but when I used sqldevelopper I do not have any problems

```
execute execute md_pkg.insert_Gr(9,25)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ORA-900: Invalid SQL statement` should give you enough clues as to what's going on/wrong. Your statement to be executed is not SQL, it is an attempt to call a PL/SQL stored procedure. So, instead of

```
"execute md_pkg.insert_Gr("+id+"," + num + ")"
```

you should (maybe! I don't know Hibernate at all) rather

```
"call md_pkg.insert_Gr("+id+"," + num + ")"
```

or

```
"begin md_pkg.insert_Gr("+id+"," + num + "); end;"
```

and instead of using the `SQLQuery` class try and find something capable of executing stored procedures or anonymous PL/SQL blocks.

PS: I don't know Hibernate at all, so I can't help you finding the correct class.